# WordPress unable to connect to the external database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am working on `WordPress`.I have an external `MySql DB` which I want to connect with my application.

I have a `php` page named accounts. In which I am trying to do the following.

```
$newdb = new wpdb( 'username' , 'password' , 'db_name' , 'host' );
$result = $newdb->get_results ( "
SELECT * 
FROM accountant
" );

var_dump($result);
die();
```

When executing this page I am getting a  result.

I have another `php` page `email` which is used to send an email. On this page, I  want to run some queries, so I am trying the same

```
$newdb = new wpdb( 'username' , 'password' , 'db_name' , 'host' );
$result = $newdb->get_results ( "
SELECT * 
FROM accountant
" );

var_dump($result);
die();
```

But when I try to execute it. I am getting `HTTP 500`. I don't know the main reason but I must be doing something wrong.

Also, I have tried to do the same in my `wp-config` but again I am getting `HTTP 500`

**Update 1**

Below is my `wp-config`

```
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
 /** The name of the database for WordPress */
 define( 'DB_NAME', 'i3105069_wp2' );

 /** MySQL database username */
 define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

 /** MySQL database password */
 define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '');

 /** MySQL hostname */
 define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

 /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
 define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

 /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
 define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to manually create a `new wpdb()` connection? That should be established already.

Comment: @tadman because The database that  I  am trying to access is external. I have added `wp-config`. You might get the idea

Comment: @Grant it says `Class 'wpdb' not found in /home/staadmin123/accountantsquote.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mytheme/email1.php on line 6`

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database You're missing the host argument.

Comment: @DeFeNdog I am unable to add the `wp-load.php` file.

Comment: wp-config.php is the file you'll want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple questions that might help weed out the issue.

1. Could you paste your remote database URI (strip/replace personal info)?
2. Are you looking to use both databases at once or only the remote DB?

If you're using remote as primary:

```
// In WP-CONFIG  
define('DB_HOST', 'https://your-remote-database/info');

// Elsewhere in your app
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM your_db.your_table" );
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

If using remote DB in addition to the primary:

```
$wpdb_b = new wpdb( "user", "password", "your_db", "https://your-remote-database/info" );
$rows = $wpdb_b->get_results( "SELECT * FROM your_table" );
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

Could you look at PHP error logs so that we know the nature of the 500 error? You could also try to catch the exception to see what is thrown.

```
try {
    $wpdb_b = new wpdb( "user", "password", "your_db", "https://your-remote-database/info" );
    $rows = $wpdb_b->get_results( "SELECT * FROM your_table" );
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($rows as $obj) :
       echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
    endforeach;
    echo "</ul>";
}
//catch exception
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```